# I can't use strong tag in wysiwyg

Tags: wysiwyg

I watch Introduction Advanced Theming in Drupal 7 (drupalize.me), and I create custom theme frot that video tutorial. I can't use `<strong>` and `<em>` in CkEditor. I can use only `<b>` and `<l>`, but CkEditor create `<strong>` and `<em>`. That tags has no effect when I save my node.
Why? What is wrong? When I change the theme to Bartic, everything works OK, but in the custom theme from that video tutorial, those two tags are not rendered as I would expect.

Answer (score 5):

CSS resets usually take the emphasis off of `<strong>` and `<em>` tags by default.

All you need to do is add a rule like this to your main style sheet (main.css):

```
strong {font-weight: bold;}
em {font-style: italic;}
```

That will re-reset the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags to display as you'd normally expect.

Comment: Tnx Clive!!!!!!

Comment: @Martins Happy to help :)